# How do I share my NIC which has internet connectivity with another NIC?

Tags: networking

On my main computer, I have one interface eth0 which uses DHCP to obtain an ip address, dns addresses and it's  gateway ip address. It has successful connectivity to the internet.

I have another interface eth1 which uses a static ip address which provides NFS services to another computer, let's call this other computer nfs-client. I want nfs-client to be able to have internet connectivity also! However i do not want to join it to the same network as eth0.

Here is a simple diagram:

```
         +-----------+             +-----------+             +-----------+ 
         |           |             |Ubuntu     |             |           | 
         |ADSL Router|-------------|Computer   |-------------|NFS Client | 
         |           |             |(2 NICS)   |             |           | 
         |           |             |           |             |           | 
         +-----------+             +-----------+             +-----------+
```

[.](http://www.fossildraw.com/draw.php?currow=1&curcol=4&font=3&grid=off&cellh=6&cellw=13&line=single&mod=smpl&clpcrow=&clpccol=&clprow=&clpcol=&scrlrow=0&scrlcol=0&olduact=clearcell&curtext=&qae=ca0&qbb=ba0ADSL%20Router&qbc=ca0&qbd=ba0Ubuntu%20Computer%20%282%20NICS%29&qbe=ca0&qbf=ba0NFS%20Client&uact=clearrow&txt_status=%2a%2a%2a%20Busy%20%2a%2a%2a&p1=1&text_cell=&p2=1)

I simply want to keep my network topology and give nfs-client internet connectivity via the main computer. How do i go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

See the answer of your second question...
https://superuser.com/questions/275124/how-do-i-share-my-internet-connectivity-to-another-nic